# How to unpack *.tar.gz

Tags: tar

I have used the command

```
tar zxvf filename.tar.gz
```

...to try to unpack the file. However, upon entering the command the screen just fills with

```
x hadoop-3.1.1/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/images/expanded.gif
x hadoop-3.1.1/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/project-reports.html
x hadoop-3.1.1/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/css/
x hadoop-3.1.1/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/css/maven-base.css
x hadoop-3.1.1/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/css/site.css
x hadoop-3.1.1/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/css/maven-theme.css
x hadoop-3.1.1/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/css/print.css
x hadoop-3.1.1/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/dependency-analysis.html
```

But it does not create an executable file (this is what I expected). What is the next step?

Comment: Is there any reason not to assume that there is no such file in the archive?

Comment: Change the options to ztvf and send stdout to a file, which will contain a list of the archive contents (similar to ls). Then read that into an editor and search, probably for permission like /r-x/. I would never extract a tar file without examining it first.

Answer (score 1):

The title isn't really your question, you obviously know how to unpack a `*.tar.gz` file, your question should be: "How to install hadoop?" or something similar.

Anyway, you really should read the documentation: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Prepare_to_Start_the_Hadoop_Cluster